# Removing underlining from image link

Tags: css, html, image, jekyll

I have a [page](http://calculemmas.github.io/posts/mapping-the-early-english-book-trade) with a single large image that also has a link element, and I'd like to remove the underlining from the image link. I am working in Chrome, which displays the highlighting under the image link and claims the css is introduced by`user agent stylesheet`, which I understand is Chrome's default css. The `user agent stylesheet` brings the following style to my page:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

How can I remove the underlining from this image link? I tried setting the id of my link and image to `img-link` then targeting that id with the following css, but haven't had any luck:

```
<a id="img-link" href="/images/post_images/mapping_early_english_books/provincial_printing.png" data-lightbox="provincial_printing" data-title="My caption">
  <img id="img-link" src="/images/post_images/mapping_early_english_books/provincial_printing.png" alt="Provincial Printing" style="width:100%" /></a></p>

#img-link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any help others can provide on removing this underlining will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#img-link, #img-link img{
   text-decoration: none !important;
   border:0px !important;
   outline:none;
   border-width: 0px;
   outline-width:0px;
   border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SaurabhSinghMehra this works perfectly! For my future reference, why do `border`, `outline`, `border-width`, and `outline-width` affect the link here?

Comment: Actually main one is text-decoration: none; but i use others to work perfectly . From  only text-decoration: none; you can easily do that also.

Answer (score 3):

just set the border property to zero:

```
#img-link {
   text-decoration: none;
   border: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: before downvoting check the real example please and also proposed solution - setting border to zero really fixes this problem, thanks

Comment: This is the only answer that worked among all. Better than all answers for all relevant questions. Should be marked as the correct answer. Many thanks!

Comment: after adding `!important` to `text-decoration` this solution works, setting border to 0 idd fixes it. thx!

Answer (score 0):

I m not pretty sure but can you try this :

```
#img-link {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

I hope it would solve it

Comment: this actualy worked just fine, so for the one who has downvoted my answer, next time you check the answer before judging, I mpretty sure its the same person who downvoted all others answers, so dont rush yourself next time, you're not God neither a big reference to have the right to judge others answers without testing them, I have respect to this community, otherwise my answer would have been formulated differently and lot less polite.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give multiple elements the same ID value.

If you want your CSS to also target an `img` element inside your element with the ID of `img-link`, use the following CSS.

```
#img-link, #img-link img{
    text-decoration:none;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem appears to be from an underline added in your css `.content a`, try adding:

```
    border-bottom: none;
```

to your img-link css

Comment: Sorry @William, no luck!